# Exception reusing HttpClient https connection

Tags: java, https, connection, httpclient

I am using apache HttpClient.  While debugging something, I found I am getting error when I execute the same HTTPS HEAD request for the second time using the same connection (connection kept alive). The host is https://dongshengcn.iriscouch.com. I am not sure where is wrong, is the server? is it a HttpClient bug? I tend to think this is a HttpClient bug somewhere. Anyways, I am wondering if someone can point me to the right direction. Here is the code and logging info:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: dongsheng
 * Date: 1/10/13
 * Time: 4:10 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class HttpClientTest {

    private int connectionTimeout = 1000;
    private int socketTimeout = 10000;
    private String host = "dongshengcn.iriscouch.com";
//    private String host = "dongshengcn.cloudant.com";
    private int port = 443;
    boolean useExpectContinue = true;

    public DefaultHttpClient configureClient() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, useExpectContinue);
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(params, connectionTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, socketTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, Boolean.TRUE);

        String protocol = "https";
        params.setParameter(ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST, new HttpHost(host,
                port, protocol));
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

        return client;
    }

    @Test
    public void test_dafault_http_client() throws IOException {
        String uri = "/ektorp-test/";
        DefaultHttpClient client = configureClient();

        org.apache.http.HttpResponse rsp = client.execute(new HttpHead(uri));
        System.out.println(rsp.toString());

        try {
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse rsp2 = client.execute(new HttpHead(uri));
            System.out.println(rsp.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



Running HttpClientTest
2013/01/11 10:12:05:288 EST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {s}->https://dongshengcn.iriscouch.com:443
2013/01/11 10:12:06:065 EST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to dongshengcn.iriscouch.com:443
2013/01/11 10:12:07:201 EST [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
2013/01/11 10:12:07:223 EST [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2013/01/11 10:12:07:223 EST [DEBUG] RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2013/01/11 10:12:07:224 EST [DEBUG] RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2013/01/11 10:12:07:224 EST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
2013/01/11 10:12:07:224 EST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: HEAD /ektorp-test/ HTTP/1.1
2013/01/11 10:12:07:226 EST [DEBUG] headers - >> HEAD /ektorp-test/ HTTP/1.1
2013/01/11 10:12:07:226 EST [DEBUG] headers - >> Host: dongshengcn.iriscouch.com:443
2013/01/11 10:12:07:226 EST [DEBUG] headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2013/01/11 10:12:07:303 EST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404 Host not found
2013/01/11 10:12:07:304 EST [DEBUG] headers - << HTTP/1.1 404 Host not found
2013/01/11 10:12:07:304 EST [DEBUG] headers - << Content-Length: 14
2013/01/11 10:12:07:307 EST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2013/01/11 10:12:07:309 EST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@21cc5069
2013/01/11 10:12:07:309 EST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
HTTP/1.1 404 Host not found [Content-Length: 14]
2013/01/11 10:12:07:309 EST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {s}->https://dongshengcn.iriscouch.com:443
2013/01/11 10:12:07:310 EST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient - Stale connection check
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: HEAD /ektorp-test/ HTTP/1.1
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] headers - >> HEAD /ektorp-test/ HTTP/1.1
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] headers - >> Host: dongshengcn.iriscouch.com:443
2013/01/11 10:12:07:311 EST [DEBUG] headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2013/01/11 10:12:07:314 EST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpResponseParser - Garbage in response: Host not found
2013/01/11 10:12:07:314 EST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:62168<->173.192.57.98:443 closed
2013/01/11 10:12:07:315 EST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:62168<->173.192.57.98:443 shut down
2013/01/11 10:12:07:315 EST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@67c7980c
2013/01/11 10:12:07:315 EST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive for 9223372036854775807 MILLISECONDS
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:909)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at HttpClientTest.test_dafault_http_client(HttpClientTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    ... 32 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.411 sec
```

If I change the host to a difference one like dongshengcn.cloudant.com:443, and it works as expected.

Comment: If you reuse the client, you use one session. So maybe: The first time the server sees you like a "new" user and the second time the server guesses you came back and sends something else as answer. From the error it's the server sending something faulty

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I do not think there is session involved, because I do not see any cookie info. I assume that is how session is created/identified. Am I right?

Comment: I think HttpClient hides the Cookie and Session stuff from the user. Maybe you can switch Fiddler2 between and compare the requests and especially the responses.

Comment: There is no cookie. I can confirm that from curl command response.

Comment: Sorry for not being very helpful. For me this really look like a HTTPClient problem. Typically HTTPClient is quite straightforward. I'm sure you also use the latest version.
Looks like you are trying to connect to CouchDB, both servers are running a different version. Maybe have it look at this. Also, if you really try to connect ot CouchDB, maybe try testing a CouchDB-Lib.
Maybe instead of Apache HTTPClient try to use Java's HttpUrlConnection: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/0050__HttpURLConnection.htm

Comment: Make sure `System.out.println(rsp.toString());` reads the entire response entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite likely the server does not correctly handle HEAD requests and sends a response body in response to the first request in violation of the HTTP specification corrupting connection state and rendering it non-reusable.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can find out more details what exactly corrupts connection?

Comment: If you have access to the server, server logs would be the place to look

Comment: You should be able to look at the irisouch logs like so: `https://dongshengcn.iriscouch.com/_log?bytes=100000`